# Eclipse :strange behaviour of PHP editor - colored blocks, etc

Tags: php, eclipse, editor

I installed the lastest version of 'Eclipse for PHP'  (Eclipse Helios).

The PHP editor behaves really strange, compared to Zend Studio (also built on Eclipse) which I used before.

Sometimes when I'm typing in the PHP Editor strange random pastel-colored blockes appear everywhere, which seem to have no meaning at all... and a few seconds later they disappear again.

Another weird thing is that some lines are in *italics*,  while there is no reason for that.

Did anybody else notice this?
What could cause these kind of things?

**UPDATE**:

I think it has something to do with Annotations. I have no idea how that all works, Eclipse is becoming some kind of a configuration nightmare....

Comment: "The PHP editor" means PDT extension?

Comment: Yes, it's the all-in-one PHP package from the Eclipse website, which includes PDT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The strange colors that I saw had to do with Annotations - PHP elements 'read'/'write' occurences

I unchecked the 'Show in text' for these annotations and it's working ok now.

Answer (score 0):

If the pastel-colored blocks appear on the right-hand side of the editor, and appear in red and yellow, those are indicators of warnings or errors on a certain line of code. These update as you modify the file, which might explain why they appear and disappear constantly as you type.

Comment: No, the blocks are on the left side, and most of the time just covering spaces, or half covering code at the end of a line and some spaces in the next line.... very weird...  The problem is that I can't really reproduce it, it happens when I sometimes click on variables, so I guess it has something to do with code-assist.

Answer (score 0):

On the left side there a blocks that point out changes in your source file made since it was last saved, I think. I would be also good to have a screenshot.